# long delay while opening folder files in ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04

Folder file appears empty for few minutes even though it contains file in it.
any solutions to get rid of this.
os is ubuntu 14.04

Comment: How many files are in the folder?  Triple indirection on your directories will slow things down. Any other processes hitting the disk at the time you are taking the directory?

Comment: Dude, I'm new to ubuntu. Almost all folders in home directory suffer long delay problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be lack of memory, or a failing disk, since your problem is not the "I have 40,000 pictures in a directory and it's slow to open" sort of thing.
Open a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-t and

1. Check the free memory

   ```
   free --human
   ```

   Post the results in your question.
2. From the install media, run the memory check to confirm it's OK.
3. From the install media, maybe run the file system check, but if this is a new install, that's probably not the problem. Command in a terminal will look like (assuming sda and partition one, change to meet your setup)

   ```
   sudo fsck /dev/sda1
   ```
4. Install the smartmontools and check your disk

   ```
   sudo apt-get install smartmontools
   sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
   ```

   (Assuming your disk is `sda`)

Comment: +1 better answer then [mine](http://askubuntu.com/a/572829/344926) so deleted mine and upvoted yours.